# grails-app/utils dir

Tags: grails

I've just noticed the existence of the `grails-app/utils` dir. I've never seen it referred to in any documentation (or used in a project). It's created by default when you run `create-app`, any idea what you're supposed to put in there?

"Utility" code is an obvious guess, but it seems like that should go under the `src` dir.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 37, accepted):

the `grails-app/utils/` directory is where items like [Codecs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#codecs) go.

I'm not sure what else goes there, but you can include other classes there and they will be included within the Application

EDIT:
The `grails-app/utils/` directory is meant for "Grails specific utilities" ([Artefacts](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ArtefactHandler.html), [GrailsClasses](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsClass.html), etc.)

Jeff Brown([Core member of the Grails development team](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/conference/speaker/jeff_brown)) responded to a [question on the mailing list](http://n4.nabble.com/grails-app-utils-not-on-the-classpath-in-STS-td1355738.html) that confirms this.  He said:

> You can put just about anything you
>   like in the `utils` directory but it is
>   really for Grails specific utilities. 
>   At the moment I think the only thing
>   really targeted at this directory are
>   custom codecs.  Your application
>   classes that are not Grails artifacts
>   should go under `src/groovy/`

You can find an example of a new Grails Artefact in the [Constriants plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/constraints).  The Author of this plugin recommends that users [put their Constraint classes in the `grails-app/utils/` directory](http://www.zorched.net/2009/10/26/announcing-grails-constraints-custom-domain-constraint-plugin/).

Comment: This information is correct for grails 2. In grails 3.0 utility classes go under `src/main/groovy/`. I suppose this might be helpful to people googling for "grails ulity classes" in 2015.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to create the util folder if it doesn't exists. By right clicking on "project -> New -> Folder" simply creates a normal folder. But in another project I saw someone created it and it is having a scissor sign. Here is the image link: 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxcLSUsfZQKHemZUR3dGSEM0WVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KamaldeepSingh Grails Projects 2.x there is the utils directory created by default. Grails 3.x not, and if you create it manually, it will be a common directory and not standard.