# how to create grails-app/utils dir

Tags: grails

Can anyone please let me know how to create the utils folder if it doesn't exists. By right clicking on "project -> New -> Folder" simply creates a normal folder. But in some another project I saw someone created it and it is having a scissor sign. Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I clone projects and they have not got default directories like **controllers** or **utils**. This situation happens if directory didn't have any files (especially default *.gitignore*) in it, while user had been pushing it on repository server (git doesn't push empty directories by default).

Usually I resolve this situation by:

1. deleting project from workspace
2. cloning project to directory outside workspace
3. manually creating missing directories (in your case it's **project/grails-app/utils**)
4. importing project to workspace with all directories

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210241/grails-app-utils-dir) you can find what **utils** directory should contain.

Comment: Yes I manually created a folder in current project but its icon is simple like other folder icon. But the utils directory in another project which I am showing is having a Scissor icon. Is it a special kind of directory or what ?

Comment: Did you follow my steps?

Comment: Yes I did the same

Comment: I'm not sure where is your problem. If you're asking if this directory has special purpose - yes and it's seldom use. I provided link with explaination why.  If you're asking about icon - it's just GGTS icon for this directory. If after making all descibed steps you still don't see this icon, tell me which version of Grails and GGTS are you using?

Comment: @KamaldeepSingh ggts can be funny try removing project (not deleting it) and  then add new grails project this will prompt it exists just open it again and it should fix it

Comment: Hey @vahid your suggestion best worked for me. But you know removing the project also removed pre set dependencies settings. Well I am setting them again. Thanx.